# Возможно ли дописывать в таблицу xml header в виде шапки документа?

Tags: c#, xml

Никогда прежде с xml углубленно не работал.

Имеем xml файл, заполняющийся посредством сериализации. После заполнения имеем таблицу с одноуровневой шапкой. Возникает необходимость добавить над таблицей некоторую информацию о содержимом, а также добавить в конец итоговое значение по одной из колонок.

Итоговое значение я подсчитываю в коде, и чисто теоретически я могу добавить строку с единственным непустым значением но остаются вопросы.

Вопросы:

1. Могу ли я добавить эту самую шапку после заполнения документа данными?
2. Как следует организовать структуру документа, чтобы все описанные действия можно было выполнять? Т.Е. может быть существуют правила подготовки документа к записи сериализованных данных?

Comment: Если вам нужно "допилить" xml до нужной формы используя какой-либо стандарт, то это можно сделать xslt-скриптом. [XSLT-преобразования](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/47yh29a9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: 2. Вариант посложнее - ручной, самый простой из ручных - пожалуй XmlWriter-ручной-прокси, он "на лету" позволяет добавлять узлы атрибуты к существующему. 3. Загрузив в XMLDOMDocument - можна "вручную" добавить узлов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно распространённым способом является следующий: создаём `XmlWriter`, с его помощью в начало документа записываем всё необходимое (шапку), потом в него же выполняем сериализацию, в конце можно дописать итоговые данные.

```
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("data.xml"))
{
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("root");
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("header", "Шапка");

    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, data);

    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("total", "42");
}
```